# How can I speed up Spring and Spring MVC startup times?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Application startup is taking is so much time more than a minute in scanning of the packages and creating application context .
applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(packages) ;

Is there any way to reduce/optimise the startup time.

Comment: attach config files please (pom etc...)